# Import Data into an Excel Spreadsheet from Google Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos, google-sheets

I have a Google Form which is populating a Google Sheet.  Then this Google Sheet I need to be able to connect to an Excel Spreadsheet.  I have been able to use the 'publish on web' method with the .csv file format.  This works great for me.  I am running a Office 365 so I have the most recent tools available to me.

The problem I am running into is that the Mac version of Excel does not offer this same connection capability.  Roughly half of my users have a Mac and so the file is not working for them as a result.  So as a result I have not been able to find a way to get the data from the Google Sheet into Excel.

This is key because this file is used by many individuals and the data to be imported is critical to enabling the solution.  The following line of code is the line that is causing the problem.  It basically is lock up Excel.

```
Sheets("Security").Range("tbl_Licensing").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Any ideas as to how I can make this work for a Mac and PC in the same manner?

Comment: It would help to explain *exactly* what you did that doesn't work for your Mac clients.  They should be able to do something like `Workbooks.Open(webPathToCsvFileHere)`

Comment: I added the line of code that is causing the primary problem.  I believe this code is retrieving the data using the connection established via Excel on a PC.  This same connection type and 'publish on web' functionality does not appear to be available.  Also the information on the file which has the data to import is confidential and as a result I don't want the other file to open.

Comment: A shot in the dark.. What happens when you remove `BackgroundQuery:=False` part from the above line?

Comment: I removed BackgroundQuery:=False and it gave me the following:  [DataSource.Error]:  Device not configured Device not configured